# Encoding binary into unicode

Tags: unicode, encoding

I have a byte array that I need to store into a `nvarchar` DB column. A `nvarchar` takes 2 bytes. What is the optimal encoding?

Ideally I would store N bytes into a `nvarchar` of lenght N/2, but there is invalid unicode sequences that worries me.

Answer (score 2):

The most optimal solution would be to store binary in a binary column. So you mean the most optimal encoding within the constraints of this suboptimal scenario?

Just go for base64, it's safe.

If you can't control the input bytes, you're bound to running into encoding problems sooner or later.

Comment: Yes, I have the stated constraints. Going base64 is safe, not space-optimal.

Comment: "*Going base64 is safe, not space-optimal*" - or, you can simply use another binary-to-text encoding.  For instance, [yEnc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YEnc) is more space efficient than base64. But there are other binary-to-text encodings available that you can play with

Comment: > But there are other binary-to-text encodings available that you can play with

@RemyLebeau That is exactly my question. What other encodings? I didn't know about yEnc. If this was an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Base64 is a good way, but you may use just Unicode code points.

Unicode codepoints go from 0 to 10FFFF, but you can encode easily and efficiently 2 bytes and an half into a Unicode code point. Depending on your requirements, you may shift all codepoints by 128, so that you have ASCII for boundaries (and you do not need to worry about byte 0, and still you have enough code points for the 20bit binary data (per code point). [Or maybe just escape 0 as 0x10000]

This is generic, for Unicode (so generic Unicode). If you know the encoding (e.g. UTF-8, you may choose different encoding).